# Json arry and other properties deserialization (C#)

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have the following json that contains an unnamed array and other named properties. I'd like to know how to deserialize it to a class, using Newtonsoft.Json.

```
  { 
    "message": "success",
    [
        {
            "timestamp": 1509723862,
            "tid": 84823616,
            "price": "7344.7",
            "amount": "0.36108123",
            "exchange": "bitfinex",
            "type": "sell"
        },
        {
           ...
        }
    ]
  }
```

I know I could deserialize the array using 
serializer.DeserializeObject< **List <  Response  >** >(serializedObject), but as the json contains other properties, it is not a json-array string.

Is there any configuration that I could use to tell Newtonsoft.Json to deserialize the array into a List, and the 'message' property to a string, in the class bellow:

```
public class Response
{
   public string Message {get;set;}
   public List<ResponseItem> ResponseItems {get;set;}

}

public class ResponseItem {
  string timestamp {get;set;}
  (...)
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to parse invalid JSON? Can't you fix it?

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem. Actually, it always gives me a valid json. If I ask https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSD, it returns a valid json array. If I request https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/BTCUSDxxx it gives me a valid json again, but this time a different one. What I am trying to do is having only one class (containing both responses). Not sure it is possible.

Comment: That json **is** invalid, put it into https://jsonlint.com/ and you'll see. You can't deserialize invalid json. Your first step should be to correct the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A JSON can't have both an unnamed array and a named value on the same level. The JSON is invalid. Either everything is keyed, or it's an unkeyed array. Can't have both.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not a good idea to concate the two Json's.
Use your own Deserializer and pass your two Json's:

```
public static class ResponseDeserializer
{
    public static Response Deserialize(string psMessage, string psResponeItems)
    {
        dynamic loMessage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(psMessage);

        return new Response()
        {
            Message = loMessage.message,
            ResponseItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResponseItem>>(psResponeItems)
        };
    }
}
```

And use it:

```
string lsMessage = "{\"message\":\"Unknown symbol\"}";
string lsResponseItems = "[{\"timestamp\":1509726632,\"tid\":84840931,\"price\":\"7298.8\",\"amount\":\"0.0044733\",\"exchange\":\"bitfinex\",\"type\":\"sell\"},{\"timestamp\":1509726630,\"tid\":84840921,\"price\":\"7297.3\",\"amount\":\"0.11550649\",\"exchange\":\"bitfinex\",\"type\":\"sell\"},{\"timestamp\":1509726630,\"tid\":84840911,\"price\":\"7297.2\",\"amount\":\"0.0214149\",\"exchange\":\"bitfinex\",\"type\":\"buy\"},{\"timestamp\":1509726629,\"tid\":84840909,\"price\":\"7297.2\",\"amount\":\"0.41004892\",\"exchange\":\"bitfinex\",\"type\":\"buy\"}]";

var loResponse = ResponseDeserializer.Deserialize(lsMessage, lsResponseItems);
Console.WriteLine(loResponse.Message);
```